# Linq Method left join two lists to get flattened list as a result

Tags: c#, list, linq, join

I am using Linq with Method syntax to LeftJoin two lists.I know this is much easier to do with Query syntax, however this is an exercise on my learning path.

```
Items.GroupJoin (
      productNonCriticalityList, 
      i => i.ProductID, 
      p => p.ProductID, 
      (i, g) => 
         new  
         {
            i = i, 
            g = g
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp => temp.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (temp, p) => 
         new  
         {
            i = temp.i, 
            p = p
         }
   )
```

It works, however as a result each List element consists of two objects `i` and `p`, and then each of them has its properties.

**Expected solution:**

I would like to flatten the structure and get as a result List with elements of all (or selected) `i` and `p` properties.

**UPDATE**

Trying to solve this I have found another version. Simplified, same result but same problem remains

```
var result= Items.GroupJoin(
                  productNonCriticalityList,
                  i => i.ProductID, 
                  p => p.ProductID,
                 (f, bs) => new
                            {
                              i = f,
                              p = bs.SingleOrDefault()
                            });
```

Comment: Is your expected output an IEnumerable of anonymous type like `{ i, p }`?

Comment: This is what I get now. To get the values I need to result.i.Property1 / result.i.Property2 / result.p.Property3. I would like to get a type of `z` (anonymous or not anonymous), where its properties would be coming from (mapped to) i & p. So this would work: result.Property1 / result.Property2 / result.Property3

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Just slight changes. Note nullable operator in `p?.Property3`, as this is left outer join, so some elements in `Items` might not have any value in `ProductID`. And I still want to get them in the result.

```
Items.GroupJoin (
      productNonCriticalityList, 
      i => i.ProductID, 
      p => p.ProductID, 
      (i, g) => 
         new  
         {
            i = i, 
            g = g
         }
   )
   .SelectMany (
      temp => temp.g.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
      (temp, p) => 
         new  
         {
            Property1 = temp.i.Property1, 
            Property2 = temp.i.Property2, 
            Property3 = p?.Property3
         }
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option1 :

From your comment it looks like you need an aggregated list where the keys come at first and the values comes in second and so on like `[i1, p1, i2, i3, p3]`:

You can use a simple `foreach` loop and build the List by your own:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in groupJoin)
{
    list.Add(item.i);
    foreach (var g in item.g)
    {
        list.Add(g);
    }
}
```

### Option2 :

If you want to use `SelectMany`, you will need to edit your `collectionSelector` to hold on the `i` key as well as its siblings `g`:

```
collectionSelector: temp => new List<object>(temp.g) { temp.i }
```

(Note that syntax of I'm initiating the `g` siblings first, and than adding the the `i` key, if you want you can edit it as your needs.)

Then, the `resultSelector` should return the transformed element of the sequence with:

```
resultSelector: (temp, p) => p
```

To conclude:

```
var selectMany = groupJoin
    .SelectMany(
        collectionSelector: temp => new List<object>(temp.g) { temp.i },
        resultSelector: (temp, p) => p
    );
```

Comment: I have found satisfying solution in the meantime. Not sure to what extend your Option2 is similar but have found it inspirational.

Comment: Glad it was helpful for you